# Displaying a string on a Datagridview using a value (integer) from a DataTable

Tags: data-binding, datagridview, datatable, datasource, dataview

How do I display a string in a Datagridview cell rather than an value from a bounded data source? I only want to change the *displayed* values.

I know that if the data is bound then you have to change the value in the data table itself. However, my data table communicates with another data table during runtime so I only want to change the display values but not the actual values.

I've searched for solutions and the closest I've got to what I'm looking for is this:

```
    dgv.DataSource = bindSource

    Dim dv As DataView
    dv = New DataView(bindSource.DataSource)

    For i As Integer = 0 To dv.Count - 1
        If dv(i).Row.Item("Type") = 0 Then
            dv(i).Row.Item("Type") = "Single"
        End If
    Next

    dgv.DataSource = dv
```

Of course this does not work since I can't change the Dataview cell data type from Integer to String.

Thanks.

Edit:

The data is taken from text files and stored into the data tables. The users can then view the data through Datagridviews. Users may do some actions but they are not allowed to sort or change specific data tables (including this one). However, they may select a row from the DGV1 and copy it into DGV2. The row will appear in DGV2 but will remain in DGV1.

After the user is done viewing the data, the data tables are stored into actual SQL Server tables. The database has its tables and columns already defined prior to the transferring of data.

Comment: You are going to be bound to the “type” defined in the data source. In most cases the line `dv(i).Row.Item("Type") = "Single"` will throw a data error if the column is of a numeric type. Is there some reason you cannot change the data source’s “Type” column to a string? There is not enough info about how the column’s behavior should be, example, is the user allowed to make changes, is the column ever sorted by the user. Are the numbers used for some numeric computation etc…

Comment: Please look at my edit. I hope I answered your questions.

Comment: _“How do I display a string in a Datagridview cell rather than an value from a bounded data source?”_ … You cannot they are one in the same. _”I only want to change the displayed values.”_ … you cannot they are one in the same. In addition to your comment… _”since I can't change the Dataview cell data type from Integer to String.”_ … this is not correct, the `DataGridView` does NOT have a built in “Integer” type column. The grid does not care what is in the cell… but the `DataTable` does. You will have to use another approach to achieve what you describe.

Comment: You're right. I'll try a different approach. Thanks.